# How would destroying the moon save the earth?

Tags: doctor-who

Spoilers for Doctor Who Season 8 Episode 7:

> In the beginning of the episode, the problem seemed to be the
>  increased mass of the moon. How can destroying the moon reverse the
>  giant tides and other effects? 
>  
>  How will destroying the moon help the earth?

Comment: Short answer: it wouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: they wanted to use the nuclear bombs not to destroy the moon, but to destroy whatever alien threat they might find on the moon.

Longer answer: [Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/) doesn't have a transcript up yet, but I did find a non-formatted transcript [here](http://iview.abc.net.au/cc/thescarf_01_07_pqzml.xml). The first meeting between the Earth expedition and the Doctor makes clear that they brought the nuclear weapons because they thought the changes in the moon might have been caused by aliens:

> Doctor: Why have you got all these nuclear bombs? No, no, no, easier
>   question - what's wrong with my yoyo?
>
> Clara: Doctor, it goes up and down.
>
> Doctor: Bingo.
>
> Clara: Oh!
>
> Doctor: A-ha. We should all be bouncing about this cabin like fluffy
>   little clouds, but we're not. What is the matter with the Moon?
>
> Astronaut: Nobody knows.
>
> Clara: Do you know what's wrong with the Moon?
>
> Doctor: It's put on weight.
>
> Astronaut: How can the Moon put on weight?
>
> Doctor: Well, lots of ways - gravity bombs, access alignment systems,
>   planet shellers...
>
> Astronaut: So, it's alien.
>
> Doctor: Must be causing chaos on Earth. The tides will be so high that
>   they will drown whole cities.
>
> Astronaut: Yeah.
>
> Doctor: So, what are you doing about it? (astronaut goes over and
>   grabs the nuclear detonator) This?
>
> Astronaut: **That's what you do with aliens, isn't it? Blow them up?**

Later, once they realize that the moon is an egg containing a giant creature getting ready to hatch, their fear is that when it hatches some pieces of the moon will hit the Earth and cause an even greater disaster than the change in the tides...and that even if the pieces miss the Earth or burn up in the atmosphere, the giant creature might still be a threat:

> Clara: If we let it live, what would happen if the Moon wasn't there?
>
> Astronaut: Listen, we haven't got time for this.
>
> Clara: We're discussing it. What would happen if the Moon wasn't
>   there?
>
> Courtney: I have a physics book in my bag. There's this thing on
>   gravity...
>
> Astronaut: Super. Is there a word-search?
>
> Clara: there would be no tides, but we'd survive that, right? There's
>   a... They've knocked out the satellites, there's...no internet, no
>   mobiles - I'm happy, fine, with that.
>
> Astronaut: It's not gonna just stop being there because inside the
>   Moon, Miss, is a gigantic creature forcing its way out. And when it
>   does, which is gonna be pretty damn soon, there are gonna be huge
>   chunks of the Moon heading right for us. Like, whatever killed the
>   dinosaurs, only 10,000 times bigger.
>
> Clara: But the Moon isn't made of rock and stone, is it? It's made of
>   egg shell!
>
> Astronaut: Oh, God. If, by some miracle, the shell isn't too thick, or
>   if it disperses, or if it goes into orbit, whatever, there's still
>   gonna be a massive thing there, isn't there, that just popped out.
>
> ...
>
> Astronaut: OK. You imagine you've got children down there on Earth
>   now, right? Grandchildren, maybe. You want that thing to get out? Kill
>   them all? You want today to be the day life on Earth stopped because
>   you couldn't make an unfair decision? Listen, I don't want to do this.
>   All my life I've dreamed about coming here. But this is how it has to
>   end.